# Probability of making a shot at least k times out of n attempts

Tags: probability, solution-verification

As an example:

> If you have a 10% chance of making a 3-point shot and make 6 attempts, what's the probability of making the shot at least 2 times?

In the above example, $x = 0.1$, $k=2$, and $n=6$.

The way I solved this specific example is as follows:

P(making at least 2 shots) = 1 - P(making no shots at all) - P(making exactly 1 shot)

P(making at least 2 shots) $ = 1 - (1-0.1)^6 - (1-0.1)^5(0.1)$ = 0.40951

So far I have derived this formula:

$$f(k,n,x) = 1 - \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} (1-x)^{n-m}x^m$$
with $k$ strictly less than $n$.

I think that this formula produces correct results. But I'm wondering why it fails in the case of $k=n$. I expect the chance of making at least 6 shots out of 6, or exactly 6 shots to be $(0.1)^6  = 0.000001$. But this formula gives me $0.327403$.

What gives? Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). There are $\binom nm$ ways to choose the $m$ successful shots, so the complete formula is

$$
f(k,n,x)=1-\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\binom nm(1-x)^{n-m}x^m\;.
$$

Since

$$
\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nm(1-x)^{n-m}x^m=(1-x+x)^n=1^n=1\;,
$$

this is

$$
f(k,n,x)=\sum_{m=k}^n\binom nm(1-x)^{n-m}x^m\;,
$$

so the case $k=n$ now comes out as you rightly expected.

Comment: One more thing, if you don't mind. How do you use this formula to find the average expected number of shots made? Would that just be

$$\sum_{m=0}^n  \binom{n}{m} m(1-x)^{n-m}x^m$$

Comment: @Reneo: The answer is: you don't :-) The expected number (that already means "average"; "average expected" is doubled) of shots made is, by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties), just $n$ times the probability $x$ of an individual shot being made. However, if you insist on doing it the hard way, then yes, that's the correct sum, and you can evaluate it like this:

$$
\left[x\frac\partial{\partial x}\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nmy^{n-m}x^m\right]_{y=1-x}=\left[x\frac\partial{\partial x}(x+y)^n\right]_{y=1-x}=\left[nx(x+y)^{n-1}\right]_{y=1-x}=nx\;.
$$